# Which records are affected by ActiveRecord dependent: destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a couple of ActiveRecord objects with associations marked as `dependent: :destroy`. When the user deletes one of those objects, I want to present him with a list of all objects that will be (recursively) removed. How do I get this list?

I found the [`affected_on_destroy`](https://github.com/murbanski/affected_on_destroy/) gem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791721/evaluating-dependent-destroy), but it's not really finished and seems to be rails 2.2. Is there some more current gem or some feature in rails to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a gem `affected_by_destroy`, the source can be found [here](https://github.com/lucas-clemente/affected_by_destroy).

Answer (score 1):

```
Class.reflect_on_all_associations.
  keep_if{ |assoc| assoc.options[:dependent] == :destroy }.map(&:name)
```

That may not be precisely what you're looking for, but I think `reflect_on_all_associations` should get you what you want.

Comment: That would be the way to do it by hand, it's also how the gem works. But somehow I feel that there should be some better way, or that someone should have implemented this already.

Comment: Every gem I've seen that deals with dependent associations (not a lot, admittedly) finds them this way. This looks like an open problem to me.